# What's the best way to have a website with multiple languages?

Tags: php, web, multilingual

I'm designing a website that is already translated into Portuguese and English.
In this moment, there are two different websites for them:

> http://yogmel.com : English version
>
> http://yogmel.com/pt/ : Portuguese version

I've done some research and I found out that that's not the best way to do it.

What's the best way to change a website's language? I already have the texts/pages translated and don't want it to be translated by a third party (Google Translator, Wix, Squarespace).

I'm willing to learn and program php if that's the best way.

Comment: Lordie, there's a ton of stuff out there.

Comment: Question is so wide, can you specify your site CMS?

Comment: You have two language versions yet. Why you hindered to add another languages?

Comment: Wait, the site is not even in PHP yet?

Comment: @Evgeniy It's not CMS.

Comment: @developerwjk I'm using php for another reason (to insert the header and footer for every page)

Comment: @Evgeniy I understand your point. I don't want to add another language - I want to change my website so the user doesn't have to manually click on the page with the right language. Neither I want to insert manually on every page a link to the corresponding language page. Example: on the yg.com/about I'd have to insert a link to yg.com/about/pt; on the yg.com/projects I'd have to insert a link to yg.com/projects/pt/. That's why I want to know the best, optimal way to have a multilingual website. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best" way is too opinionated but the ***simplest*** way is basically you need some way to keep a phrase by phrase table of translations. The key field would be the phrase in the main language (or a unique identifier thereof), with other fields for the translation in each language, and you print the phrase to the page by calling a function that takes the parameters of the phrase in the main language and the target language.

```
<div>
  <p><?php echo translate('Welcome to the site', $targetLanguage); ?></p>
  <p><?php echo translate('Our company is committed to excellence!', $targetLanguage); ?></p>
 <!-- if using identifier approach instead: -->
 <p><?php echo translate('Paragraph_of_company_propaganda', $targetLanguage); ?></p>
</div>
```

The database here could be an actual database, or a big PHP array, depending on how you want to do it.

A list of languages the user's browser claims they accept can be found with `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` which should return an array with the most acceptable language first. The languages will be represented by a two character code like EN, ES, FR....

Comment: Thank you very much developerwjk! One last question: is it a very advanced php technique? Sorry for my noobness

Comment: @yogmel Its as simple as writing a function `translate()` that searches a 2d array by key text and then target language. The advanced part is maintaining the array when it has to be updated. Putting it in a separate file that you include will help a bit, but still it could become a pain to maintain without writing some kind of utility to convert say an Excel file to the array or something.

Comment: @yogmel You also have to deal with storing the non-Roman alphabet languages in UTF8 which is not that big of a deal.